# Integration tests for a Rails Shopify application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, shopify, ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth

I am trying to write controller / integration tests for my Shopify application built with Rails 5 and the [shopify_app](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app) gem.

The problem I am facing is I can't find out how to bypass the authentication process in my test environment. I can't find the correct method to stub.

What I tried:

```
#test_helper.rb
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Turn on "test mode" for OmniAuth
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
end
```

.

```
#products_controller.test.rb
class ProductsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    # Add OAuth mock provider
    # Sets authentication hash to return during integration testing
    @shop = build(:shop)
    OmniAuth.config.add_mock(
     :shopify,
     prodiver: :shopify,
     uid: @shop.shopify_domain,
     credentials: {
       token: @shop.shopify_token
     }

     # This get request gets redirected to http://www.example.com/
     get shopify_app.auth_shopify_callback_url, params: {shop: @shop.shopify_domain}
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get root_url, { env: {
      "omniauth.auth" => OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:shopify],
      "omniauth.params" => { shop: @shop.shopify_domain }
    }}
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Test result:

> Failure:
>   ProductsControllerTest#test_should_get_index [/shopify_stock_exporter/test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:7]:
>   Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <302: Found> redirect to http://www.example.com/login

Questions:

- is this the correct way to set the request's env variable?
- what should the mock return to simulate a successful authentication?

Related resources:

- [mock_shopify_omniauth](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing) method from the shopify_app gem
- [Omniauth wiki](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing)

Comment: As messages said, you have been redirected to login page, so I think that you have some authorization there and you need to be logged in to view this page.

Comment: The question is about how to stub the shopify_app authentication/authorization process to have the test succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Since `shopify_app` uses `omniauth` for authentication, you should check out the omniauth wiki: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing

You'll need to set `OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true` and then use `OmniAuth.config.mock_auth`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it definitely helped me go in the right direction. Still haven't managed to have the test pass though.. I updated my question.